# Pyinstaller exe python file gives error requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pyinstaller

I am making a tkinter app that shows if you have messages or not on a small drag and drop coding website called scratch. But when I turn it into an executable using pyinstaller and run it, it gives me an error. I looked up how to fix it, but I got an answer I didn't understand, so please assume I'm a noob programmer, and give me an answer in simplest terms. I am using windows 10 and python 3.9.

The command I used:

`pyinstaller --onefile sly.py`

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests\packages\urllib3\util.py", line 608, in ssl_wrap_socket
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 309, in send
  File "requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 539, in urlopen
  File "requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 366, in _make_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1253, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 948, in send
  File "requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 127, in connect
  File "requests\packages\urllib3\util.py", line 612, in ssl_wrap_socket
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sly.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "requests\api.py", line 55, in get
  File "requests\api.py", line 44, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 357, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 480, in send
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 480, in <listcomp>
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 137, in resolve_redirects
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 460, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 358, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is my code:

```py
import time, requests, json, os, threading, webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pyautogui as pag

def set_interval(func, sec):
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec)
        func()
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return t
#starts the session
isError = True
while isError:
    usersname = pag.prompt(text='Please enter your username.', title='Scratchly') #pag is pyautogui
    req = requests.get("http://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/{}/messages/count/".format(usersname))
    jl = json.loads(req.text)
    try:
        test = jl["code"]
        pag.alert(text="Incorrect username")
    except:
        isError = False

#gui stuffs
root = Tk()
scriptDir = os.getcwd()
scriptDir = scriptDir.replace('\\', '/')

#images
messageImage = PhotoImage(file = "{}/images/message.png".format(scriptDir))
messageRecieved = PhotoImage(file = "{}/images/messagerecieved.png".format(scriptDir))
move = PhotoImage(file = "{}/images/Move.png".format(scriptDir))
togl = True

#define
def Move_On():
    global togl
    if togl:
        root.overrideredirect(0)
        togl = False
    else:
        root.overrideredirect(1)
        togl = True

def buttonShow(widget):
    widget.pack()
def buttonHide(widget):
    try:
        widget.pack_forget()
    except:
        pass

#attributes
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.overrideredirect(1)

#widgets
messageButton = Button(root, image=messageImage, command=lambda: webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://scratch.mit.edu/messages'))
messageRecievedButton = Button(root, image = messageRecieved,command=lambda: webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://scratch.mit.edu/messages'))
moveButton = Button(root, image=move,command=lambda:Move_On()).pack(side=TOP)

#set's up for the buttons
def check_messages():
    r = requests.get("http://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/{}/messages/count/".format(usersname))
    count = json.loads(r.text)
    count = count["count"]
    if count > 0:
        buttonHide(messageRecievedButton)
        buttonShow(messageRecievedButton)
        buttonHide(messageButton)
    else:
        buttonHide(messageButton)
        buttonShow(messageButton)
        buttonHide(messageRecievedButton)

#main loop
check_messages()
set_interval(check_messages, 10)
root.mainloop()
quit()
```

Comment: pls paste the command you have used for pyinstaller to convert it to exe.

Comment: @simpleApp I used this command: `pyinstaller --onefile sly.py`